# Electron-compile how to use scss or at least css with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, electron, electron-forge

I'd appreciate an example on how to work with `scss` or at least with `css` together with `ReactJs` and `Electron-compile`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[electron-prebuilt-compile](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt-compile) helps you with that. From [their own provided example](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt-compile#installation):

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="main.less" />
</head>

<body id="host">
  <script type="application/javascript">
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import TodoApp from './components/TodoApp';

    ReactDOM.render(React.createComponent(TodoApp), document.getElementById('host'));
  </script>
</body>
```

If you want to use webpack you can have a look at [electron-webpack](https://webpack.electron.build/) which have [add-ons](https://webpack.electron.build/add-ons) to handle React, SASS, LESS, etc.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this, but the problem there is that it covers only the global file, the one file, that you can include in your application. This limits the flexibility. Say you have a component, then how would one add a component-specific stylesheet? This is something that is a normal thing to be done with React.

Comment: As you don't provide any examples it's hard to help you. I guess you've tried `import './style.less'` from your React component?